# How can I make a local Git hook run a Windows executable and wait for it to return?

Tags: windows, git, bash

I'm working in a Windows environment. I have a Git repository and am writing a custom pre-commit hook. I am much more comfortable writing a quick and dirty console application in C# than trying to figure out Perl syntax so that's the route I'm going.

My `.git/hooks/precommit` file looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
start MyHelperApp.exe
```

And this works somewhat. As you can see I have a compiled helper application in the root of the repo directory (and it is .gitignore'd), and this does indeed launch my application successfully when I call `git commit`. However, it doesn't wait for the process to finish nor does it seem to care what the return code of the process is. I assume this is because `start` is asynchronous and *it* returns a 0 exit code every time.

I have reason to suspect that the `start` process which is getting called here is not the native Windows `start` command, because I tried changing it to `start /wait MyHelperApp.exe` but this had no effect. Also trying to call `MyHelperApp.exe` directly gives a "command not found" error, and so does changing `start` to `call`. I suspect that start is an emulated bash command and it's running the bash version instead of the Windows version?

Anyways, my helper app does return different exit codes depending on different conditions, so it'd be great if those could be used. (Pre-commit hooks fail if a program in the script returns any exit code besides zero.) How might I go about utilizing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the executable directly, don't use `start`.

> Also trying to call `MyHelperApp.exe` directly gives a "command not found" error

If the `PATH` variable doesn't contain a `.` entry, bash won't look in the current directory to find executables. Call `./MyHelperApp.exe` to make it explicit that it should be run from the current directory.

Comment: This is great -- one of those "this should have been obvious to me, duh" moments. Also interesting that I just learned I cannot pass in command line arguments to this that use a forward slash; they have to be the kind of command line arguments that begin with a hyphen. Since I'm writing the helper app myself that is easy enough to adjust, but I found that strange.

Comment: @SoaperGEM If it starts with a forward slash, then MSys interprets it as a path name and converts it to a Windows-style path. Double the slash to indicate that you want a literal slash: pass `//a` from your hook, and your program will see `/a`.